# Facebook Scraper

Tags: python, facebook, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Post and images from this facebook profile; https://www.facebook.com/carlostablanteoficial and getting nothing when trying to reach the actual post text with this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.facebook.com/carlostablanteoficial")

res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html5lib");
resdiv = res.div
post = resdiv.findAll('div', class_='text_exposed_root')
print(post)
```

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Comment: good evening dear Juan Hernandez - many thanks for the great example. Its awesome! 
 BTW :  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?

Answer (score 2):

This will return many results:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get("https://www.facebook.com/carlostablanteoficial")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print(div)
```

to search for a specific class, change the loop to:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class', 'text_exposed_root'}):
    print(div)
```

but when I tried it returned nothing, meaning there is no div with that class on the page

Comment: Hello and good day dear BpY -- many thanks for the answer:  well i found out that we can scrape fb eg: see here: https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/
question: well can i scrape fb pages for a special key category - eg. 
female and  single  - is this possible!?